# Bluemix Connect and Compose

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant, connect-compose

I have a Cloudant database which has a images as attachment to the document. A sample document looks like this

```
{
     "_attachments": {
        "smiley.png": {
           "content_type": "image\/png",
           "digest": "md5-Xxwpc\/\/87878gthgygf==",
           "length": 25148,
           "revpos": 2,
           "stub": true
        }
     },
     "_rev": "4-08f5ecebd8024a967706564972f31f79",
     "id": "3e88e50d5a7095897d4544d3ed4118ab",
     "age": 10,
     "name": "Smiley",
     "dob": 10102000,
     "gender": "male",
     "gadget": "watch"
  }
```

Using Connect and Compose created API for basic CRUD operations.  I added data using the API and for attachment used the Cloudant dashboard and added image as attachment.
Now when I retrieve the data using REST API in my javascript code, I can retrieve the JSON as above and get all the details.  I am not sure how to get the image and display it in my webpage.

```
function getCatalog()
{
    var input = {
            method : 'get',
            returnedContentType : 'application/json',
            path : 'connect-api-prod-dfd-cc0e-11e5-b246-ffdf/connect_compose/031bcc30-cc0e-11e5-b246-8fd1e5139db0/user_db',
            parameters : {

            },
            headers : {
                "X-IBM-CloudInt-ApiKey" : "HHURI1FJTkFLT0ZZZzdWTFQ1OUYyTkIxSERIuvehisDhWSEM4RksyWg=="
            }
    };

    var response = WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
    return response;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://docs.cloudant.com/attachments.html#read),

> To retrieve an attachment, make a GET request to https://$USERNAME.cloudant.com/$DATABASE/$DOCUMENT_ID/$ATTACHMENT. The body of the response is the raw content of the attachment.

So in your above example the path to the attachment would be:

```
connect-api-prod-dfd-cc0e-11e5-b246-ffdf/connect_compose/031bcc30-cc0e-11e5-b246-8fd1e5139db0/user_db/3e88e50d5a7095897d4544d3ed4118ab/smiley.png
```

Comment: I tried that, if it was a direct call to Cloudant that works.  Since I am going through connect and compose that gives me an error message.